# Add directory to WinCE image on Platform Builder

Tags: .net, filesystems, windows-ce, platform-builder, bsp

What should I do on `Platform Builder (6.0R3)` in order that the resulting image of a BSP I am working on, to have a directory named "abc" in the file system root. In addition, this directory has to have some files (executable and dll generated on `.NET Compact 3.5`).

I have searched, but only found how to add files to the Windows directory by editing `Platform.bib`, but not how to create a new directory with certain files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `platform.dat` file for Creating a directory and/or copying files to directory.

The commands, or file parameters, in DAT files are:

- `root`, which designates the root folder.
- `Directory(“<Directory name>”)`, which is used to both designate a
  folder and to create a new folder.
- `Permdir(“<Directory name>”)`, which is used to create a new folder
  that cannot be deleted by the user.
- `File(“<destination file name>”, “<source path and file name>”)`, which
  is used to copy a file.

**Create a folder**

You can use `DAT` files to create a folder, or folder tree.

This is exactly what the DAT files in the Public folders do to create the directory structure that you see when you boot your system.

Example of creating `\MyFolder\SubFolder` using `platform.dat`:

```
root:-Directory("MyFolder")
Directory("\MyFolder "):-Permdir("SubFolder ")
```

Which does the following:

1. Creates a folder named MyFolder in the root of the file system.
2. Creates a folder named SubFolder in \MyFolder which cannot be
   deleted

`Directory()` is used in two ways; one to create a directory, and the other to specify a folder in which the new directory will be created.

**Copy a File to a Folder**

You can also use `DAT` files to copy files from the `\Windows` folder to one or the newly created folders.

Example of copying `MyApp.lnk` to `\MyFolder\SubFolder`:

```
Directory("\MyFolder \ SubFolder "):-File("MyApp.lnk", "\Windows\ MyApp.lnk")
```

Which copies `\Windows\MyApp.lnk` to `\MyFolder\SubFolder\MyApp.lnk`.

But what if you want to rename the file:

```
Directory("\MyFolder \ SubFolder "):-File("MyNewName.lnk", "\Windows\ MyApp.lnk")
```

Which renames `MyApp.lnk` to `MyNewName.lnk` when it copies it to `\MyFolder\MySubfolder`.

Source : [**Platform Builder: Using Dat Files to Initialize the File System - A blogpost by Bruce Eitman**](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/17/platform-builder-using-dat-files-to-initialize-the-file-system.aspx)